# What is the difference between init() and OnInit()?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

I am learning MQL4. On their reference website, creating a custom indicator is done like as follows:

```
#property indicator_chart_window

int init(){
    return(0);
}

int deinit(){
    ObjectsDeleteAll();
    return(0);
}

int start(){

    return(0); 
}
```

But when I create a new Indicator from inside the MetaEditor, I get another syntax, like this:

```
int OnInit()
 { 
 //--- indicator buffers mapping

 //---
 return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
            const int prev_calculated,
            const datetime &time[],
            const double &open[],
            const double &high[],
            const double &low[],
            const double &close[],
            const long &tick_volume[],
            const long &volume[],
            const int &spread[])
 { 
//---

//--- return value of prev_calculated for next call
return(rates_total);
}
```

Why is it different?

Is there a web link, or book someone can refer me to?
From what I read the best place is the MQL4 website, but it looks different and I am not sure where to turn to now.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

### Where the observed difference comes from?

An **`MQL4`** language has moved ( somewhere about a MetaTrader4 Terminal LiveUpdate release Build 572 .. 6xx ) a "half-step" towards another generation of the MetaQuotes programming language ( named an `MQL5` ).

While `MQL4` language has spanned many years and is a mature and stable, both in concept and execution, the "new"-MQL4 introduces things, the "traditional" MQL4 language ( and the code-execution environment ) were not ready to use.

So, the observation you have made, is right due to the "old"-syntax code snippets residing on many web pages and a "new"-syntax, pasted inside a blank/new <kbd>Indicator</kbd> template by a "new"-`MQL4`-IDE.

### What to do with that in practice?

Your "new"-syntax will work on any post-Build-572+ MetaTrader4 Terminals. You need not worry about an "incompatible" case, where "new" code would be colliding with an "old"-terminal, as MetaTrader4 Server has an internal setting, which dictates the "oldest"-allowed Terminal the Server is willing to allow to connect and serve. As a matter of fact, that means you will newer be able to connect / run a pre-Build-572 MetaTrader4 Terminal connected to a broker side, where the "new"-code could collide with "old"-syntax rules.

Anyway, for a sake of an `MQL4` syntax disambiguation, there is a compiler directive available:

```
#property strict             // read MQL4-IDE Help file for more details
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So what I am getting from what you are saying and please correct me if I am wrong: To buy a book MQL5 and study that instead of MQL4?

Comment: Salutes to Scotland,Jamerfjr! First, let me excuse not to dare recommend anything without a proper knowledge about all  your needs and the target application development context. I can't say anything without taking care of these important pieces of information. **Nevertheless**, the dilemma is not in place. MQL5 has come after many years of silence and the "server-side" of the business -- the FX Brokers -- do not move into the MQL5 direction any fast ... and not only God knows why ... So, in case your Project goes seriously into Production-grade system, do not hesitate to ask more, or email me

Answer (score 2):

There are some changes to the MQL4 after build 600.
The `OnInit()` is the Init-event handler. You can still use `Init()` as it is backward compatible. `OnInit()` is the newer practice.

Some of the online documentations are outdated and are not yet updated.
This link provide info on the changes: http://docs.mql4.com/mql4changes